# With Struts Logic Iterate Tag what type is required for iterating over SelectOption class

Tags: java, struts

I have Googled for which library this class belongs to but I'm struggling to find any real definition of it. (apart from the ubiquitous Options and Select tags)

```
<logic:iterate id="label" name="assetListForm" property="optionList" indexId="index" type="????">
```

I cannot find what type this is (I'm starting to think I'm missing something obvious)

In case I have been elusive about the SelectOption class the object is used like so..

```
List<SelectOption> optionList = new ArrayList<SelectOption>();
optionList.add("id", "label");
```

Any help would be great... Thanks!

Comment: So, you're using the type in your source code, but are unable to know the type? Well, the type is SelectOption, and its package is listed in the imports of your class. Why do you use an obsolete taglib (logic) of an abandoned framework (Struts)?

Answer (score 0):

List will allow add one object at the time. see the [add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) signature.

Use like this

```
SelectOption option = new SelectOption();
optionList.add(option );
```

instead of `optionList.add("id", "label");`

Comment: Thanks... but this was not the question I was asking.